# Oracle .dmp file

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an oracle .dmp file, and no access to a local oracle install..

Is there any way I can read the data or open it in another program to see what data is in this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the `.dmp` files are generally meant to be read and imported by Oracle's `imp` tool

> If that's it, don't waste your time. DMP files are to be read by
>   Oracle's IMP utility and nothing else
>   (you could, of course, use any editor,
>   but you're close to see nothing useful
>   in there).

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/64809/42800/

---

Seems if you have a licensed copy of Toad, you can use the DBA utilities to view the files

> The DBA utilities in TOAD has File
>   Browser that allows you to view export
>   files. Although I think this function
>   is only available in a fully licensed
>   copy of TOAD.

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/64809/42800/

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a feel for what's in there, open it with Vi or Notepad++ or some other reasonable editor and you can see the DDL statements scattered throughout. A lot of the data will be intelligible as well. However, it IS a binary file, so making a lot of use of it is problematic. Also, if it's huge, the editor you use may not be able to handle it, so you might want to use a pager like less.

That said, can't you download the Oracle Client software and install it? The administrator utilities in there include imp/exp IIRC.